# String encoding related issue

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, encoding

I have a custom xml serializer which can serialize types and the method signature is:

```
string result = CustomXmlSerializer.Serialize(someObject);
```

the result of the serialization I want to make it available in a web page something like :

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"somefilename.xml\"");
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Response.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=utf-8";
string content= CustomXmlSerialize.Serialize(someObject);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
Response.OutputStream.Write(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);                        
Response.End();
```

However the generated xml has still the string in-memory encoding (utf-16)? How is that possible? I am writing to the `HttpResponse` an array of byte with encoding utf-8?

Comment: perhaps you should add xml to your tags

Comment: the generated file is correct, but it has <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> and it should habe <encoding="utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

Ask your `CustomXmlSerializer` to emit a correct encoding attribute in the header. It cannot know what encoding do you use when you convert the result to bytes.